# Is there a one-liner to convert '1234567' into ['1234', '567', '', '']?

Tags: javascript, one-liner

I need to convert a string into an array with 4 elements, each element has maximum of 4 characters.

- `"1234567812345678"` -> `["1234", "5678", "1234", "5678"]`
- `"12345678123"` -> `["1234", "5678", "123", ""]`
- `""` -> `["", "", "", ""]`

The reason I want it to be a one-liner is that I need to put it into vue template string so it needs to be an expression other than a series of statements.

I don't want to create a dedicated function to just convert a single parameter to another form.

I managed to split the string into an array but I don't know how to fill in empty slots with `''`, here's a simplified snippet:

```js
const creditcard = '12345678123';

// need a one liner
const groups = creditcard.split(/(?<=^(?:.{4})+)/);

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: `const groups = creditcard.padEnd(16, ' ').split(/(?<=^(?:.{4})+)/).map(v => v.trim());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pad the string to minimum 16 characters with spaces, then trim the results

```js
const creditcard = '12345678123';

// need a one liner
const groups = creditcard.padEnd(16, ' ').split(/(?<=^(?:.{4})+)/).map(v => v.trim());

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to allocate an array with four elements and populate it with splices from your input:

```js
const input = '111122223333444';

const output = Array(4).fill().map((_, i) => input.split('').splice(i*4, 4).join(''));

console.log(output);
// ["1111", "2222", "3333", "444"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) you can achieve your goal

Here is the code:

```js
function splitToArray(n) {
  const ret = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 16; i += 4) {
    ret.push(n.slice(i, i + 4))
  }
    
  return ret;
}

console.log(splitToArray(''));
console.log(splitToArray('1234567812345678'));
console.log(splitToArray('12345678123'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need an expression, not a function :/